# Can't log in to new Web2Py installation

Tags: web2py

Apparently this is a common problem (with an answer) but I haven't seen the answer being shared.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/EUXZ2aoKA50

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/web2py/WEXWcAP52IY/YE1BU4esRc0J

I just installed Web2Py on my hosted site and I can't log in to the admin panel with the correct password. If I put in a wrong passwords it says the password is wrong. If I put in the right password, it says nothing and reloads the login page.

---

Edit: Cookies, while mentioned as one possible solution (try it and it might fix yours) are not the problem on my system. The person on the google forum found some other solution after saying cookies didn't fix his either.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was shared but you didn't catch it.

Solution: If cookies are disabled in the browser login will fail.

UPDATE: Check for HTTPS !

The administrative interface, admin, is only accessible from localhost unless you run web2py behind Apache with mod_proxy. If admin detects a proxy, the session cookie is set to secure and admin login does not work unless the communication between the client and the proxy goes over HTTPS; this is a security measure. All communications between the client and admin must always be local or encrypted. More [details](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview) in web2py book.

Comment: That wasn't solution for him and it isn't for me either. He found something after that that fixed it.

Comment: Are You sure? I have intentionally tested it. After I disabled cookies, I got the same error as you did! I have tried it with IE.

Comment: Yes. I'm sure. See screenshot. (I'm +1-ing this because it *is* a valid solution when cookies are a problem. Just doesn't happen to fix mine)

Comment: Any more idea: According to web2py book, ch.29... "The administrative interface, admin, is only accessible from localhost unless you run web2py behind Apache with mod_proxy. If admin detects a proxy, the session cookie is set to secure and admin login does not work unless the communication between the client and the proxy goes over HTTPS; this is a security measure. All communications between the client and admin must always be local or encrypted"

Comment: I think you're on it with the https. I completely forgot that. Let me test and see.

Comment: Nice! The problem was https vs http. Want to add it to your answer and I'll accept? (A link to the documentation you referenced would be awesome for the next person)